# Node/EJS: Looping through JSON object with multiple parent/child objects

Tags: arrays, node.js, json, ejs

I am having a bit of trouble parsing a large JSON object that has multiple parent/child objects. Here is the JSON.

```
checklistItems = [
{"Firewall":[
{"fwSetDoc": {"desc": "Review Firewall Settings and Update Documentation"}},
{"fwLogDoc": {"desc": "Review Firewall Login Creds and Update Documentation"}},
{"fwLicDoc": {"desc": "Firewall Licenses and Update Documentation"}},
{"fwWarDoc": {"desc": "Firewall Warranty and Update Documentation"}}
]},

{"Server": [
{"srvAvInst": {"desc": "Server Anti-Virus Installed"}},
{"srvAvUtd": {"desc": "Server Anti-Virus Up To Date"}},
{"srvBkup": {"desc": "Server Backups"}},
{"srvDsk": {"desc": "Server Disk Space"}},
{"srvWinUpd": {"desc": "Server Updates"}},
{"srvF1": {"desc": "Server Error Boot F1 to continue disabled"}},
{"srvOpenm": {"desc": "Server OpenManage Alertsn"}},
{"srvWar": {"desc": "Server Warranty"}},
{"srvCabUps": {"desc": "Server Cabling and UPSs"}},
{"srvPerf": {"desc": "Server Performance Check"}},
{"srvMonAlert": {"desc": "Server Monitoring and Alerts"}},
{"srvAppSvc": {"desc": "Server Application Services"}},
{"srvSecSet": {"desc": "Server Security Settings"}},
{"srvUsrPerm": {"desc": "Review Domain Users and Permissions"}},
{"srvFsSet": {"desc": "Review Server Fileshare Settings"}},
{"srvGpoSet": {"desc": "Review GPO Settings"}},
{"srvMonAgt": {"desc": "Server Monitoring Agent Installed"}}
]},

{"Network": [
{"netDevConf": {"desc": "Review Network Device Configs\\Logins and Update Documentation"}},
{"netDevWar": {"desc": "Review Network Device Warranty and Update Documentation"}}
]},

{"Workstation": [
{"wsAVInst": {"desc": "Workstation Anti-Virus Installed"}},
{"wsAVUtd": {"desc": "Workstation Anti-Virus Up To Date"}},
{"wsWinUpd": {"desc": "Workstation Updates"}},
{"waMonAlert": {"desc": "Workstation Monitoring and Alerts"}},
{"wsSecSet": {"desc": "Workstation Security Settings "}},
{"wsMonAgt": {"desc": "Workstation Monitoring Agent Installed "}},
{"wsMonAgtCln": {"desc": "Monitoring Agent Cleanup (Inventory Comparison Against Onsite Count)"}}
]}
]
```

I need to create a table in EJS that separates each parent object with its child objects and 'desc'.

An example of output would be

```
<th> Firewall </th>
<td>Review Firewall Settings and Update Documentation<td>
<td>Review Firewall Login Creds and Update Documentation<td>

<th>Server</th>
<td> ... </td>
```

I have tried:

```
<%checklistItems.forEach(function(cat){%>

              <%});%>
```

which will return the whole list of objects, but I cannot seem to access the child obj or 'desc' of said objects.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the format of the object always the same pattern? Like Firewall-> Server ->Network ->WorksStation ?

Comment: Yeah, however the number of child objects differs.